How does one determine the cardinal direction in which analemma was photographed?
Given an analemma, I am confused by how to obtain any useful information from it. Initially I thought you can at least determine the latitude of photographes, but this is clearly not the case, as it's tilt can be completely different, even if taken at the same location, as can be seen from the images here; I can't explain why that happens.
Now I wonder if one can at least determine which cardinal direction the photographer was facing when taking the photo? For example, if we are in the northern hemisphere, does the summer solstice being left to the winter solstice mean something else then the converse? Or is this also something that can't really be determined from the image alone.
And additionally, how is the sun's daily motion related to this? How can we say in which direction it is moving and does it depend on the latitude or cardinal direction we are facing?

This doesn't directly answer your question, but explores a lot of variables that produce the analemma shape.https://mtirado.com/blog/demystifying-the-analemma/

Does the information you have include the angular distance and direction  between points on the analemma and the local idealized horizon?

Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/55836/16685 & links therein.

Also, I have a program here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/55736/16685 (that runs in your browser) that makes 3D Analemma diagrams for any location & time. Note that it reverses the analemma shape because you're viewing the celestial sphere from the outside.

@DarthPseudonym I've done a number of skyfield simulations of the analemma, andI believe you are incorrect to say that the Analemma has a different shape depending on location; the two lobes are the effectively the same relative size, regardless of observation location on Earth, or chosen time of day, with the more northerly lobe being the smaller.

Animated Analemmas showing the position at all local times of day from:  Quito, Ecuador, Boston, MA and the North Pole

The analemma will be the same everywhere on Earth.  Observers will have to rotate themselves different directions to view it, but they are all viewing that same thing.

I may have to ask a question about that, then.
